# how to stop input reset on live ajax searchbar

Tags: javascript, ajax

I am trying to make a live ajax searchbar on keyup event.

When I type one character the page changes url and resets my input text. How can I prevent the page from refreshing as I write more characters?

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    function getSearch(str){


        var u = document.getElementById("search").value;
        if(str.length == 0){
            status.innerHTML =  'field is empty';
        }
        if(u != "") {

            se.onreadystatechange = function(){
                if (se.readyState == 4 && se.status == 200){
                    status.innerHTML = se.responseText;
                }
            }

         }
     }
</script>
```

Comment: @LelioFaieta You're not clear on ajax. Even though the page reloads, *there has been an ajax request*.  Wether the page reloads or not is not relevant. AJAX is ajax by itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your ajax request lacks some configuration. You need to tell the request itself which url it should call, and specify the method. Just change those lines:

```
status.innerHTML = 'Verifying...';
//window.location.replace("search.php?search="+str);
// this is why your page reloads. you want to remove this
var se = new XMLHttpRequest();
se.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
se.onreadystatechange = function(){
    if (se.readyState == 4 && se.status == 200){
        status.innerHTML = se.responseText;
    }
}
se.open('POST',"search.php?search="+str);
// you need to open the request, specifying the method and the url
se.send();
```

here is an interesting [read on ajax requests](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest)

Comment: Yes i tryed that but the problem is that a new page comes up on top of the old one ,that is why i put window.location.replace("search.php?search="+str);  insted of se.open('POST',"search.php?search="+str);

Comment: this means your `var status = document.getElementById("inner");` takes too broad an element. be sure to select the element in which you want to replace content, *and* make sure that `search.php` returns just the html you want, **not** a whole html page with `<head>` and `<body>`